# Set/Change Display(Name="") Attribute of a Property in Controller/ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, displayname-attribute

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446961/2949081) answer from 2010, regarding mvc-2, it wasn't possible. What about now, in asp.net-core 2.2?

My usecase:

I have a `BaseViewModel` that is being used by 2 views: `TableView` (for users) and `TableManagentView` (for admins). The `BaseViewModel` is invoked by a `ViewComponent`. Here are some samples:

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel {
    [Display(Name = "Comment")
    public string UserComment { get; set; }
}
```

TableView:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(Base), new { myObject = myObject, stringName = "User"})
```

TableManagementView:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(Base), new { myObject = myObject, stringName = "Admin"})
```

Base:

```
public class Base : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(BaseViewModel myObjet, string invokingView)
    {
        // here i want to do something like that
        if (invokingView == "User") {
            myObject.UserComment.SetDisplayName("My Comment");
        } 
        if (invokingView == "Admin") {
            myObject.UserComment.SetDisplayName("User's Comment");
        }


        return View("BaseViewComponent", myObject);
    }
}
```

BaseViewComponent:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserComment)
```

The `BaseViewModel` is simplified, but there are a lot more attributes. The reason I want to do this is to avoid code duplication in both tables. The only thing that should change are the label names.

I've tried `reflection`, but without success:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(BaseViewModel myObject, string invokingView)
    {
        MemberInfo property = typeof(BaseViewModel).GetProperty("UserComment");
        property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute)).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single().Name = "test";

        return View("BaseViewComponent", myObject);
    }
```

The `Name` doesn't change and remains `"Comment"` from the initial setting.

If it's not possible to set the attribute name programmatically, what other solutions do I have? I'm thinking about `ViewBag/ViewData` or `TempData`, but this solution doesn't appeal to me. What would be the pro's and con's of that?

Comment: What about your objects having concrete types (baseViewModel is abstract), and you have `UserViewModel` and `AdminViewModel` and both implement an interface that gives you the correct label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the comment I left, one way you could solve this is by having your `BaseViewModel` being an abstract class and have concrete classes deriving from it. So `UserViewModel` and `AdminViewModel`. These two concrete classes would then be the models for both `TableView` and `TableManagentView` and would be responsible for telling the "outside world" how to label fields.

The base class has two main aspects (apart from your normal fields): An abstract `Dictionary<string, string>` which will contain the labels and a method to get the label from the list: `string GetLabel(string propName)`. So something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    protected abstract Dictionary<string, string> Labels { get; }

    public string UserComment { get; set; }

    public string GetLabel(string propName)
    {
        if (!Labels.TryGetValue(propName, out var label))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Label not found for property name: {propName}");

        return label;
    }
}
```

Then you create the two deriving classes `User` and `Admin`:

```
public sealed class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected override Dictionary<string, string> Labels => new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { nameof(UserComment), "User label" }
    };
}

public sealed class AdminViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected override Dictionary<string, string> Labels => new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { nameof(UserComment), "Admin label" }
    };
}
```

They only implement the `Dictionary<string, string>` and set the appropriate text for each field on the base class.

Next, changing your `BaseViewComponent` to this:

**View**:

```
@model DisplayNameTest.Models.BaseViewModel

<h3>Hello from my View Component</h3>

<!-- Gets the label via the method on the base class -->
<p>@Model.GetLabel(nameof(BaseViewModel.UserComment))</p>

<p>@Model.UserComment)</p>
```

**ComponentView class (simpler now)**

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(BaseViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Finally, changing your views `TableView` and `TableManagentView` to this:

```
@model WebApp.Models.AdminViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>Admin View</h1>
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Base", Model)
</div>
```

and the Controller to:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var adminViewModel = new AdminViewModel { UserComment = "some comment from admin" };
    return View(adminViewModel);
}
```

Now when you navigate to `TableView`, you'll pass a `UserViewModel` to the `BaseViewComponent` and it will figure it out the correct label. Introducing new fields will just now require you to change your viewmodels, adding a new entry to the Dictionary.

It's not perfect, but I think it's an okay way to solve it. I'm by far not an MVC expert so maybe others can come up with a more natural way to do it as well. I also prepared a working sample app and pushed to GitHub. You can check it out here: [aspnet-view-component-demo](https://github.com/joaopgrassi/aspnet-view-component-demo). Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: This solution is both elegant and beautiful. I like how you abstracted things and used the `Dictionary`. Never occurred to me to use it this way. I always thought of viewmodels as standalone containers. 
Any particular reason for making the derived classes `sealed` or having them in the same namespace? Or is it just a convenience to make the sample more readable?

Comment: Glad it was useful! Yeah, the derived classes should have separated files, I just put them together for convenience. They don't have to be sealed, but I like doing it to express the intent that these should not be sub-classed. They are "final".